# JavaScript innerHTML creating a blank page

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I'm trying to make a site where when the image is clicked text will appear above it. The problem I'm having is that when the image is clicked instead of text appearing the whole page goes blank. Any ideas why this is or how to fix it?

Html:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Six Degrees of Seperation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sepstyle.css">
</head>

<body>

<center><img id="ban" src="pic\banner.png"></center>

<div id="name"></div>

<input type="image" id="un" src="pic\unscroll.png" onclick="open()">

</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="JJs.js"></script>

</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function open(){
    var x = "dfs";
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = x;
}
```

Comment: Assign var x = "dfs"; above document.getEl....

Comment: I made the switch and still run into the same problem

Comment: Always use unique function names in javascript close() open() get() and such other common function names are taken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you walk through the door than open it?

```
function open(){
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = x;
    var x = "dfs";
}
```

No, you open it and than walk through, You are trying to use the variable x before you defined it.

The other issue is open is already taken, it means window.open(). You need to rename it to something else.

```
function openMessage(){
    var x = "dfs";
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = x;
}
```

and

```
<input type="image" id="un" src="pic\unscroll.png" onclick="openMessage();">
```

Comment: I made the switch and still end up with the blank screen

Comment: inside the `<input>` tag i have `onclick="open()"`

Comment: Just updated it, did not look at your variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Rename your function

... as open is already defined to open a page http://devdocs.io/dom/document.open

```
function openIt(){}
onclick="openIt()"
```

by the way: why do you use an input with type image and not an ?

Comment: an input with type image is like a submit button. 

It will submit a form and redirect to a given page (). You do not have a form-tag and so it redirects to a blank page. http://de.selfhtml.org/html/formulare/formularbuttons.htm#grafische